# "for only" vs. "only for"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I'm confused about how a placement of "only" can change the meaning of a sentence.

A real life text from the document I'm working on:

> If possible, use the shorthand syntax: `#` for an ID, `.` for a role, `%` for each value of the `option` attribute (which is used **for only** tables), `x*y` for consecutive table column specifiers.

> If possible, use the shorthand syntax: `#` for an ID, `.` for a role, `%` for each value of the `option` attribute (which is used **only for** tables), `x*y` for consecutive table column specifiers.

The reality is that `option` attribute cannot be used with anything except tables. For instance, you cannot use it with lists or images.

I'm concerned that one of the versions above actually tells something different: that *"We are talking about the cases where `options` attribute is applied to tables. However, it can be used with, for example, lists or images as well. The use of `options` attribute is not limited to tables."*

Is it correct to say that "for only" and "only for" have different meaning? Which version is correct here?

Comment: **For only** does NOT work. The only correct constructions are **only for tables** or **for tables only**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"(which is used for only tables)" is sufficiently unnatural that I would call it just wrong, particularly in US technical English (but I suspect in other forms as well)

Here I would use "(which is used only for tables)" invariably. A comment suggests "(which is used for tables only)". This is acceptable, but in my experience is less common.

I can't cite a more general rule of which this is an example.